# Designable Macro on Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently developing custom macros for recording interviews. 
These macros are placed on the interview minutes.

The macros have the standard picture of recording/play/pause. But I would like to be able to distinguish when the record is active or inactive by looking at the macro buttons.

Do you know if it is possible to have a pushbutton with two differents photos:

- one when it is pushed
- another one when it is not activated

OR If it is possible to modify the colors of the pushbutton when its status changes.

Comment: what kind of button do you have- `CommandButton` or a simple `form button` or maybe some other shape working like button? Show us the beginning of your code which starts recording...

Comment: It is actually a Command Button. Do you know if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can add you custom task/events to the office UI ribbon. I've mentioned a link where the use can manipulate/change the icons when a function/task is in execution.

Link:
http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/ribbon_images_labels_part_IV.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. It is actually quite interesting but do you know if it possible to reflect the state of the button by changing its color without having to be in the ribbon?

Comment: Yes, you can also set one color of the button during click event and another color after the event is completed.